# SQL Insert Select x times

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I have an INSERT SELECT query which works to insert a single record, but I need it to insert the same record x times, where x is a field returned from the database.

Here is the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO pool(stop_id) 
SELECT stop_id
FROM parts p 
LEFT JOIN stops s ON s.id = p.stop_id
WHERE p.place_id = 5054 AND s.limit IS NOT NULL;
```

Here is an attempt to insert x times which fails with syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO pool(stop_id) 
SELECT stop_id
FROM parts p 
LEFT JOIN stops s ON s.id = p.stop_id
WHERE p.place_id = 5054 AND s.limit IS NOT NULL
GO s.limit;

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GO s.limit' at line 6
```

Comment: The x in the question is a synonym for s.limit? and you want to insert duplicate rows to the number of s.limit? What if the left join returns null for s.limit? sample data and desired outcome as text would help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesn't have a GO

There query would look like,

The order is vital, as tables are by nature unsorted

```
INSERT INTO pool(stop_id) 
SELECT stop_id
FROM parts p 
LEFT JOIN stops s ON s.id = p.stop_id
WHERE p.place_id = 5054 AND s.limit IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY s.limit
LIMIT 1000;
```